# Azure Web App: Can't find variable: require

Tags: javascript, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, require

I'm running Flask app on Azure. I have a arcgis js globe that I have in the browser. It starts like:

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.22/"></script>

<script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/SceneView",
      "esri/layers/TileLayer"
    ], function (Map, SceneView, TileLayer) {
...
}
```

It works perfectly on my localhost but when I deploy it to Azure I get an error with the require([ line: `Can't find variable: require`

I have reverted my build to a time where it would work just fine, and I still get the error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your complete code if possible (excluding sensitive information)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully deployed arcgis js globe in azure

Here are the steps

1. **Install Flask**:

Before you begin, make sure you have Flask installed. If not, you can install it using pip:

```
pip install Flask
```

2. **Create Flask App**:

Create a new Python file (e.g., `app.py`) and set up a basic Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

3. **Create the `templates` folder**:

Inside the same directory as your `app.py` file, create a folder named `templates`. This folder will be used to store the HTML templates that Flask will render.

4. **Create the HTML template**:

Inside the `templates` folder, create an HTML file (e.g., `index.html`) that contains the ArcGIS JavaScript Globe and includes the ArcGIS JavaScript API script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ArcGIS JavaScript Globe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/esri/themes/light/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewDiv" style="height: 600px;"></div>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/"></script>
    <script>
        // Add your ArcGIS JavaScript API code here to initialize the Globe
        require([
          "esri/Map",
          "esri/views/SceneView"
        ], function(Map, SceneView) {
          var map = new Map({
            basemap: "streets"
          });

          var view = new SceneView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            camera: {
              position: [7.654, 45.919, 5182],
              tilt: 45
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

5. **Local Run and Deploy the Flask app to Azure**:

Open a terminal or command prompt, run the Flask app:

```
   python app.py
```

This will start the Flask development server, and you should see an output like `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`
[image]

Later, Deploy your Application to azure, Once deployment is Successful you can see the output

After Deploying to azure:

[image]